# What is the RegExMatch equivalent in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I get the equivalent of regexmatch in apps script?

Spreadsheet example:

```
A1 = "ThisIsA2018Test"
B1 = "IsA(\d){1,4}Test"
```

`REGEXMATCH(A1,B1)` returns true...

How would I match this using Google apps script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of the Google Sheets built-in function REGEXMATCH in Google Apps Script / JavaScript is [RegExp.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
var A1 = "ThisIsA2018Test";
var B1 = "IsA(\\d){1,4}Test"; // Please note that `\d` was escaped by adding a `\`
var test = new RegExp(B1).test(A1);
console.info(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, according to [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en&pli=1),

```
REGEXMATCH("ThisIsA2018Test", "IsA[0-9]{1,4}Test")
```

- Copy and paste A1 in A2 for instance
- Copy and paste B1 in B2
- In C2, `=REGEXMATCH(A2, B2)` returns true

and

```
REGEXMATCH("ThisIsA2018Test", "IsNOTA[0-9]{1,4}Test")
```

in C3 returns `FALSE`.

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /IsA[0-9]{1,4}Test/gm;
const str = `ThisIsA2018Test`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/7d2Ja5/1/)

Comment: The question is about using regular expressions on Google Apps Script. The first part of the answer is about using GoogleSheets built-in functions, not Google Apps Script, the demo use JavaScript features that are not well implemented on Google Apps Script like `const` (it works very similar to `var`) and other that not are supported by default like arrow functions.